# How can I update OpenGL on my Linux machine?

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-16.04, intel-graphics, opengl

I am trying to run a game called "Unturned" and I get an error saying that OpenGL version needs to be 3.2 or higher.

```
Unable to find a supported OpenGL core profile
Failed to create valid graphics context: please ensure you meet the minimum requirements
E.g. OpenGL core profile 3.2 or later for OpenGL Core renderer
[Vulkan init] extensions: count=1
[Vulkan init] extensions: name=VK_EXT_debug_report, enabled=0
Vulkan error VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER (-9) file: /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/GfxDevice/vulkan/VKContext.cpp, line: 305
Vulkan detection: 0
No supported renderers found, exiting

(Filename:  Line: 560)
```

This is the output that I'm getting from `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I'm running Linux Mint 18.2
CPU: Intel i5-3320M (4) @ 3.300GHz 
GPU: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller

Comment: You cannot. The OpenGL version is determined by the graphics card installed.

Comment: Can't I do anything about that?

Comment: @szymex73 - OpenGL support is handled by the Intel driver.  There is also a hardware component to this support, however, Intel HD 3000 GPUs appear to support OpenGL 3.x.  Your current OpenGL profile only supports OpenGL 3.0

Comment: Did you do any research or web searching before asking here? I ask because our Ubuntu sister site has a few questions dealing with pretty much exactly what you're asking: https://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005564/unable-to-update-opengl-to-4-x-from-3-3 https://askubuntu.com/questions/882628/updating-opengl-support-ubuntu-16-04-lts-mesa-12-0-6 https://askubuntu.com/questions/814530/how-to-update-opengl-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-with-intel-graphic-card